# Apache CFX Schema validation - contract first

Tags: web-services, validation, schema, cxf, contract-first

I am developing a Web service using Apache CXF and contract first approach with schema validation. Problem is, that validation is not working. There is no error, so it like is not activated. But validation [is configured](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?).

So, I have took a look to official Apache CXF examples you can find [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/).

I took a look to [wsdl_first](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first/) example and modify it adding schema validation and some restriction in WSDL:

```
<!-- HTTP Endpoint -->
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:customer="http://customerservice.example.com/"
    id="CustomerServiceHTTP" address="http://localhost:9090/CustomerServicePort"
    serviceName="customer:CustomerServiceService" endpointName="customer:CustomerServiceEndpoint"
    implementor="com.example.customerservice.server.CustomerServiceImpl">

    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
            <!-- schema validation-->
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

To my surprise, it doesn't work either.

OK, so I took a look to [wsdl_first_xmlbeans](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_xmlbeans/) example, where according with the README.txt file, *it also shows how CXF configuration can be used to enable schema validation*.

And for this example, schema validation works. The difference between both examples is that the second one use *JAX-WS APIs and with the XMLBeans* approach. Does it have something to do? Why schema validation is not working for first example? Probably, I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For validation on the service side, it would likely need to have a wsdlLocation attribute set on the jaxws:endpoint so it would load the WSDL (that would then contain the schemas).   Currently, the validation in that example is on the client side only.   If you run the service, the log shows:

```
INFO: Creating Service {http://server.customerservice.example.com/}CustomerServiceImplService from class com.example.customerservice.CustomerService
```

which shows it's not using the WSDL at all.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Running Jetty (configuration from cxf-servlet.xml) and added wsdlLocation attribute, it works. However, I can't make it work with default server configuration (mvn -Pserver). Which config file should I edit? cxf.xml? Not working